# Can't Install Cyberghost VPN

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu, vpn

OS: Elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera (Ubuntu 18.04.04 LTS)

I Downloaded the VPN Package for Ubuntu 18.04 and received an Error:

```
CyberGhost Installer ...

No LSB modules are available.
No LSB modules are available.
Checking if glibc version is compatible
Couldn't detect a valid version of your distribution.
Make sure you have downloaded the correct install package for your distribution
Note: We support only the following distributions for Debian based OS:

-Ubuntu 16.04 
-Ubuntu 18.04 
-Ubuntu 19.04 
-Ubuntu 19.10 
-Ubuntu 20.04 
-Linux Mint 19.2 
-Linux Mint 20
-PopOS 19.10 
-Kali 2019/2020 (glibc version should be 2.29/2.30/2.31 in order to work)
```

The script of the install.bh:

```
#!/bin/bash

    # if user is not running the command as root
    if [ "$UID" -ne 0 ]; then

        # output message
        echo "Please run the installer with SUDO!"

        # stop script
        exit
    fi

    # check update
    apt update > /dev/null 2>&1

    # output message
    echo -e "\nCyberGhost Installer ...\n"

    # get GLIBC version
    glibcVersion=$(ldd --version | grep -i ldd | awk -F' ' {'print $5'})
    
    # get distribution version
    ubuntuDistroVersion=$(lsb_release -sr)
    distroName=$(lsb_release -a | grep -i "Distributor ID:" | awk -F' ' {'print $3'})
    distroVersion=$(lsb_release -a | grep -i "Release:" | awk -F' ' {'print $2'})   

    echo "Checking if glibc version is compatible"
    

    # check if GLIBC version is compatible
    if [ "$ubuntuDistroVersion" == "16.04" ]; then
            
        if [ "$glibcVersion" == "2.23" ] ; then

            echo "The glibc version is compatible, continue..."

        else

            echo "THe glibc version is incompatible, exiting setup..."
            exit

        fi

    elif [ "$ubuntuDistroVersion" == "18.04" ] || [ "$distroName" == "LinuxMint" ]; then
        
        if [ "$glibcVersion" == "2.27" ]; then
        
            echo "The glibc version is compatible, continue..."
        
        else
        
            echo "The glibc version is incompatible, exiting setup..."
            exit

        fi

    elif [ "$ubuntuDistroVersion" == "19.10" ]; then

        if [ "$glibcVersion" == "2.30" ]; then

            echo "The glibc version is compatible, continue..."

        else

            echo "The glibc version is incompatible, exiting setup..."
            exit
        fi

    elif [ "$distroName" == "Kali" ] || [ "$ubuntuDistroVersion" == "19.04" ] || [ "$ubuntuDistroVersion" == "20.04" ]; then

        if [ "$glibcVersion" == "2.29" ] || [ "$glibcVersion" == "2.31" ] || [ "$glibcVersion" == "2.30" ]; then

            echo "The glibc version is compatible, continue..."
        
        else

            echo "The glibc version is incompatible, exiting setup..."
            exit
        
        fi

    elif [ "$distroName" == "Linuxmint" ] && [ "$distroVersion" == "20" ]; then
        
        if [ "$glibcVersion" == "2.31" ]; then
            echo "The glibc version is compatible, continue..."
        else
            echo "The glibc version is incompatible, exiting setup..."
            exit
        fi

    else

        echo "Couldn't detect a valid version of your distribution."
        echo "Make sure you have downloaded the correct install package for your distribution"
        echo "Note: We support only the following distributions for Debian based OS:"
        echo ""
        echo "-Ubuntu 16.04 "
        echo "-Ubuntu 18.04 "
        echo "-Ubuntu 19.04 "
        echo "-Ubuntu 19.10 "
        echo "-Ubuntu 20.04 "
        echo "-Linux Mint 19.2 "
        echo "-Linux Mint 20"
        echo "-PopOS 19.10 "
        echo "-Kali 2019/2020 (glibc version should be 2.29/2.30/2.31 in order to work) "
        exit

    fi          


    # define required packages
    requiredPackages=(curl openvpn resolvconf wireguard)

    # loop through packages
    for package in "${requiredPackages[@]}"; do

        # set package
        p="$package"

        # if package is opwireguardenvpn
        if [ "$package" == "wireguard" ]; then

            # check if wireguard ppa exist
            responseCode=$(grep ^ /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* | grep -c wireguard)

            # if ppa does not exist
            if [ "$responseCode" == "0" ]; then

                # install wireguard ppa
                add-apt-repository -y ppa:wireguard/wireguard > /dev/null 2>&1
                apt update > /dev/null 2>&1
            fi

            # change package name
            p="wg"
        fi

        # check if package is installed and get exit code
        responseCode=$(which "$p" > /dev/null 2>&1; echo "$?")

        # output message
        echo -n "Check if \"$package\" package is already installed ... "

        # if package is installed
        if [ "$responseCode" == "0" ]; then

            # output message
            echo "Yes"

            # if package is openvpn
            if [ "$package" == "openvpn" ]; then

                # get openvpn version
                openvpnVersion=$(openvpn --version | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}')

                # get major version
                majorVersion=$(echo "$openvpnVersion" | awk -F. '{print $1}')

                # get minor version
                minorVersion=$(echo "$openvpnVersion" | awk -F. '{print $2}')

                # output message
                echo -n "Checking OpenVPN version ... "

                if [ $majorVersion -ge 2 ] && [ $minorVersion -gt 3 ]; then

                    # output message
                    echo "Latest ..."
                else

                    # output message
                    echo "The OpenVPN version is too old ... "
                    echo "Removing old package ... "

                    # uninstall package
                    apt remove "$package" -y > /dev/null 2>&1

                    # output message
                    echo -n "Installing new package ... "
                    curl -s https://swupdate.openvpn.net/repos/repo-public.gpg | apt-key add -
                    echo "deb http://build.openvpn.net/debian/openvpn/stable xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-aptrepo.list
                    apt update > /dev/null 2>&1
                    apt install "$package" -y > /dev/null 2>&1

                    # output message
                    echo "Done."
                fi
            fi
        else

            # output message
            echo -n "No, installing ... "

            if [ "$package" == "openvpn" ]; then

                # get openvpn version from apt
                openvpnVersion=$(apt show openvpn|grep "Version:" | awk '{ print $2 }')
                version=$(echo "$openvpnVersion"| awk -F'-' '{print $1}')
                
                # get major version
                majorVersion=$(echo "$version" | awk -F. '{print $1}')

                # get minor version
                minorVersion=$(echo "$version" | awk -F. '{print $2}')

                # if version is lower then 2.4
                if [ $majorVersion -ge 2 ] && [ $minorVersion -lt 4 ]; then
                    curl -s https://swupdate.openvpn.net/repos/repo-public.gpg | apt-key add -
                    echo "deb http://build.openvpn.net/debian/openvpn/stable xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-aptrepo.list
                    apt update > /dev/null 2>&1
                fi
            fi


            # install package
            apt install "$package" -y > /dev/null 2>&1

            # output message
            echo "Done."
        fi
    done

    # output message
    echo "Continue ..."

    # if directory exist
    if [ -d /usr/local/cyberghost ]; then

        # remove directory
        rm -rf /usr/local/cyberghost
    fi

    echo "Installing application ..."

    # if logs directory does not exist
    if [ ! -d /usr/local/cyberghost ]; then

        # create logs directory if not exist
        mkdir /usr/local/cyberghost
    fi

    # copy certificates to local directory
    cp -r cyberghost/* /usr/local/cyberghost

    # change directory permissions
    chmod -R 755 /usr/local/cyberghost

    # output message
    echo "Create symlinks ..."

    # if symlink exist
    if [ -L /usr/bin/cyberghostvpn ]; then

        # remove old symlink
        rm /usr/bin/cyberghostvpn
    fi

    # create symlink
    ln -sf /usr/local/cyberghost/cyberghostvpn /usr/bin/cyberghostvpn

    # setup application
    cyberghostvpn --setup
```

I'm new to Linux so I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

I did tweaked it to look like it supports 2.34 in the install.sh file but it returned with errors

take a look at the picture.

first one is from my terminal
other one is from the cyberghost response team

and i'm runnning kali 2022.3 glibc version 2.31

[image]

[image]

any Ideas or is it just cyberghost 2022.3 won't work with glibc 2.34 ?
there should be another way to bypass it. Shouldn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the installer checks and seeing it uses `lsb_release`, i can suggest a 'dirty' way of bypassing it and making it return what it needs to in order for the installation to continue.

You can try editing the `/etc/lsb-release` file and make it look like the one from Ubuntu 18.04, something like this:
[image]

Remember to revert the changes after the installation completes. Also, if everything works fine, consider reaching out to the Cyberghost and ask them to support elementary OS too.

Answer (score 0):

So type "ldd --version" and this will tell you what version of glibc you have. Prob. 2.32..   Then change directory into the cyberghost install folder and "sudo nano install.sh"   go down to the kali versions and change 2.31 to 2.32.   hit ctrl+x, enter, enter..   then relaunch the install file.. "sudo bash install.sh"

Answer (score 0):

It is better to alter the script, which is a bit dumb:

- check if the distro release is OK in ./install.sh
  (in my case, I had "$distroVersion" == "20" although my distro is 20.3
- check if your gcc version matches
  (in my case it was)

Note that if the gcc version is very different you'll have execution errors. Only works for "close enough" situations.